# UILabel size changes when UITableView scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an old objective c project which has an `UITableView`. All the `UILabels` in each cells have been created by code. This is my `cellForRowAtIndex`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *metadataListTableIdentifier = @"MetadataListTableViewCell";

MetadataTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:metadataListTableIdentifier];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [theListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[MetrixListScreenManager setCellDataDictionary:dict];
if (cell == nil || cellReloadCount <= cellReloadLimit) {

    cell = [MetrixListScreenManager generateCellForListScreen:self withReuseIdentifier:metadataListTableIdentifier andScreenId:self.screenId];

    cellReloadCount++;
}

[SkinApplicationUITableViewController applySkinColorToRelevantControlsForCell:cell];

[MetrixListScreenManager populateCellDataForListScreenId:self.screenId usingCell:cell andDataRow:dict];
return cell;
```

}

According to this implementation, in `generateCellForListScreen` method, all the labels are creating by giving fixed height and width. Then in `populateCellDataForListScreenId` method all the texts are setting for previously created `UILabels`. Now we want to make to adjust cell height according to the content height. So what I did was in generate cell method I got the text height and replace the predefined height with that. But my problem is when I scroll some `UILabel`'s height getting increased and rest of the `UILabel`s are going beyond the cell bottom margin. What is the proper way to do this? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Adjusting cell height is in the delegate tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @GeneCode I am adjusting it. But my problem is UILabels are overlapping/height changes of some UILabels and its not behave like expected way (When scroll. During the initial load all good. Weird things happens when scroll it)

Comment: the overlapping is because you adjust only the label size but not the cell size. you need to adjust both accordingly.